# Неверно извлекаются записи

Tags: php, sql, limit

Пытаюсь организовать постраничный вывод контента на сайте, но столкнулся со следующей проблемой - игнорируется лимит при SQL-запросе, хотя и лимит подсчитывается верно, и параметр принимается, в любом случае выкидывается только контент первой страницы, не далее.

Вот код:

```
$p = $_GET['p'];
// кол-во записей на страницу
$topage = 20;
// Если страница нулевая, присвоим номер 1
(!$p) ? $p=1: $p;
// Для правильного смещения страниц уменьшим номер страницы на 1.
$p = $p-1;
// От
$start = $p * $topage;
// До
$end = $start + $topage;
$limit = "$start, $end";
//echo $limit; 

$getTopics = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `posts`  LIMIT ".$limit." ORDER BY `id` DESC");

/*
Подстановка данных под шаблон.
*/
```

При выводе `echo $limit` выдает правильно - при первой странице 0,20, при второй 20-40 и т.д.
 но в данные вытаскиваются всё равно, как при первой странице.
var_dump() отдаёт в любом случае LIMIT 0,20

Как так то?

UPD: Разобрался, в чем причина! Но вот почему, и как исправить - не понял.

В .htaccess через RewriteRule менял пути.

С

`t.php?id=([0-9])`

На

`topic/([0-9])`

При переходе по УРЛ вида `/topic/([0-9])?page=([0-9])` съедался конец УРЛА, содержащий `?page=`

А при переходе по не преобразованному УРЛ всё нормально подсчитывало. 
В .htaccess по этому перенаправлению лежит след.код

`RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)? t.php?id=$1 [L]`

Убирал флаг [L] - всё равно съедался кусок урла.

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фраза LIMIT должна быть последней и в ней упоминается не первое и последнее, а смещение и число записей. То есть чтото вроде

```
"… LIMIT " . (($_GET['p'] - 1) * $num) . ", " . $num
```

Comment: Изменил на 

$getTopics = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `myforum_posts`  WHERE `topic_id` = :id LIMIT ".$start.",".$end."");

Эффект тот же.

Comment: *$end* ? что вы изменили, кроме того, что стали использовать подготовленный запрос?

Comment: подправил пост, сомотрите.

Comment: Я вижу, что вы по прежнему неправильно формируете LIMIT. По поводу mod_rewrite стоит создать отдельную тему. Это сильно другой вопрос :)